# SQL Server "Failed to open the explicitly specified database" Event Code 18456

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We recently removed a very little used database from our system and attempted to remove all references from it in our codebase.  Even if any were accidentally left, they can not be called very often.  This was a very fringe database for us.  (We have a couple others that are more widely used)

Ever since then, we keep getting this windows event thousands of times a day (our site gets heavy traffics with DB connections virtually 24/7).

```
instance of Win32_NTLogEvent
{
    Computer = "------.-----.com";
    EventCode = 18456;
    EventIdentifier = 3221243928;
    Logfile = "Application";
    RecordNumber = 8799305;
    SourceName = "MSSQL$---";
    TimeGenerated = "20180110164152.000000-000";
    TimeWritten = "20180110164152.000000-000";
    Type = "Audit Failure";
    EventType = 5;
    User = "---\web";
    Category = 4;
    CategoryString = "Logon";
    Message = "Login failed for user '---\web'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MyDB'. [CLIENT: ---]";
    InsertionStrings = {"---\pciweb_srv", " Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MyDB'.", " [CLIENT: ---]", "-----"};
};
```

I checked the user logon mapping and there are no associations to this database whatsoever.  I am not exactly sure when this logon event is triggered.

Where else can I look for references of this missing database?  This error/event does not seem like it is from something left in the code base but more of a configuration settings with SQL Server.  However, I don't have access to out production code (Classic ASP), only what is staged in our git repo.  So if something was left outside of that, this is the only thing that makes sense if it is code.

But I can't say for sure as I am not the database admin but just a dev trying to help our Ops team track this down.

Comment: When your application connects to server, it's using a connection string. This connection string can be embedded in the code or be read from some config/ini file/registry. And this connection string may contain InitialCatalog = MyDB

Comment: @sepupic thanks. Did check this and it is not attached to that.

Comment: A bit confused by the edit.  Was the original message incorrect, or did you just edit to bump the question to the front page?  If the latter, may I suggest offering a bounty instead.  Editing to bump is bad form.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I had no idea this would cause it to be bumped.  This is not an issue I am trying to resolve and barely remember asking it.  I got a notification about this really old question and looked at it.  I saw a couple things that I didn't want to be shown due to personal info.  (Not uber confidential, just rather not have it there).  Anyhow, I don't remember what this about and apparently never got an answer for it.  I am opening to removing this question to be honest.

Comment: If there's any chance that the question and suggested answer might help another person in the future, it's probably worth keeping.

Comment: (If you really wish to delete the question, you can flag your own post for moderator attention and select the "other" reason, then explain you're looking to scrub some personal info.  Under normal circumstances, you could delete your own post, but you have an upvoted answer.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler thanks good idea.  I'll leave it around then.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to open the explicitly specified database '**MyDB**'.

Search your code repo and configurations for any references of 'MyDB' as the database being called and remove them.

Comment: This was the first thing we did.  However, if code calling the DB is the only way that this can happen it is probably something that wasn't staged in our repo (which would be an issue our end if that is true).

Comment: Also, you said, and "configurations".  Are there any examples of where?  I checked in the login mappings.  Not sure where else I can look?

Comment: I'm not sure what your architecture is but if there are config files or external references (like database connections stored in a password safe or something) then those need to be checked as well.